# Use of an apostrophe in place values of a number

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, mathematics

In mathematics, when you’re discussing the concepts behind different number bases, it’s often necessary to refer to a digit's place. For example, for the number **217** (in base 10, i.e., the number system most people normally use), you’d say:

> There’s a 2 in the hundreds place, a 1 in the tens place, and a 7 in the ones place

However, I’m uncertain where, (if at all), I should use a possessive apostrophe:

> 2 in the hundreds place
>   2 in the hundred's place
>   2 in the hundreds' place

This seems like the perfect intersection of mathematics making up terms and debates about possessive apostrophes and plurals.  Is there a general rule or consensus for this sort of usage?

Comment: Opinions among writers and grammarians differ on whether to use an apostrophe, however many sources are against both systematic use and systematic avoidance of it, especially in your latter case.

Comment: An argument could be made for both _hundreds_ and _hundreds'_ but not for _the hundred's_. The latter indicates there is a specific 'hundred' and this is its place.

Comment: At some point don't things like this just morph into the simple form by way of long usage ? E.g., Middle English *to morow* morphed from the Old English *to morgenne* (which I'm guessing is some derivation of German *Morgan*) and similar *today* from *to-day* etc.  So things like apostrophes which might just seem irksome get dropped off after a while ?  Just curious, I looked through a bunch of math books (I have a ton) all six I found that contain number systems place holders use "ones" "tens" "hundreds" sans the apostrophe.

Comment: @HowardPautz yeah, I was trying to decide if this is a  plural possessive or a simple plural  and couldn't. I think it could be read both ways. If you found six cases in math books, I'd say that constitutes an answer, it's got references and everything! :)

Comment: @terdon indeed ... trying to dig up a couple of much older text books c.a. 1940 - 1950 to see how they did it then (you, back in the day when things were more formal :)  This is a weird one, isn't it? Sort of like Fish and Fishes ... but that's different of course. Can you think of others like this ?

Comment: Well, according to [this](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/t/tom+lehrer/new+math_20138395.html) Tom Lehrer himself did not use the apostrophes and I will accept no higher authority than he!

Comment: @terdon LOL that was a fun read. Thx. Sure wish I had had him for a math teacher!

Comment: @HowardPautz Me too (wish that I had Tom Lehrer for a math teacher, that is)! Thank you for finding that and sharing with us, terdon. I shuddered at using **hundreds'**. That looks unnatural.

Comment: @FeralOink I've been a Lehrer fan since my Dad first played [_Poisoning Pigeons in the Park_](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhuMLpdnOjY) to me. There is a nice collection of his stuff on youtube ([this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIlJ8ZCs4jY&feature=share&list=RD02yhuMLpdnOjY) is probably my favorite), they should be listened to, not read!

Comment: @AlanStorm please note the answer below - have put a lot of time tracking this down (I'm interested in this topic too) ... noticed you've got a high rep on SO, so you certainly know the value of an accepted answer --- hint hint :))

Comment: @AlanStorm good - I'm cool with that too as I might be adding in more notes. (Am trying to figure out a way to post a version of your OP on Mathematics.se (or maybe meta.mathematics.se) without having it slammed back "this should be asked on ELU or ELL :)) BTW, I found 11 more text books that have this usage (but not the phrase exactly as you've posted). And @ Atsuto Nagatomo - can you link to one of the sources you say that are for or against such usage? Frankly, I've not seen any such argumentation specific to this, plural possessive nouns and genitives yes, but not these which differ.

Comment: @HowardPautz I like to leave things open for a few weekdays to see if any other answers come in — accepted answers usually means people move on. (love you answer though!)

Comment: @AlanStorm thx for the accept - I have a feeling this one won't die :)) The "apostrophe" is like a loose nuke ... LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although perhaps not as authoritative as Tom Lehrer (See terdon's comment under OP ), here are some examples from text books:

> " ***Place value*** - [...] a particular position in a place-value notation, for example, **units**, **tens**, hundreds [...] " 1)

And, though referring to the right side of the decimal place:

> " ***Decimal*** - [...] The first position to the right of the point (representing tenths) is [...] A decimal fraction is [...] a number of tenths, plus a number of hundredths, plus a number of **thousands**, etc. [...]" 2)

And from a much older dictionary my father had (for which he paid a whopping USD $0.60 [ah, that'd be six **tenths** of a dollar :-P ] ), we have:

> "***Decimal System*** - [...] 20,349 = 9 units + 4 tens + 3 hundreds + 0 thousands + 2 **tenthousands**. [...]" 3)

[Interesting, the editor parser flags "tenthousands" and offers tries to pull it apart to 'ten thousand' or hyphenate to ten-thousands. I guess our dear SE. programmers have not read reference #3. ]

[EDIT - clarification based on side discussions]

The problem, or confusion here is that these units (tens, hundreds, etc.) can be singular or plural units (similar to Fish), but also can be ***like*** *adjectives*. Perhaps a linguist can chime in here with the correct term (quantifier adjective, a "naming noun" (see below) ?).

So, consider that

> 2 in the hundreds place

is exactly the same structure as

> 2 in the red place

We'd never say "2 in the red's place" - red is not a noun, neither is "hundreds" here. The units are labels modifying "place". What place? The hundreds place. The hundreds go in that place, but they don't possess it.

Consider it another but similar way. I have two boxes, one red, one blue. And I have a bunch of marbles. I'd say "I put 2 marbles in the red box and 4 in the blue [box]"  I'd never say "marbles in the box belonging to red, " likewise not "marbles in red's box."

It's the same with hundreds - we put 2 units of something into the place holder which has these unit labels attached.  Part of the confusion is that they all end in "s" ... so I would not be surprised if an author were tempted to think them as nouns, but I have not seen it yet.

Does that make sense?

[EDIT 16 SEPT 13 Found another reference. Though just a blog, it gives a nice simple answer.]

> First and foremost, the apostrophe should NEVER EVER EVER be used to
>   show a plural (that is, any naming word [a noun] with –s on the end). 
>   For example, noodles, chocolates, flowers.  This is also true of
>   numbers and dates – tens, hundreds, thousands (10s, 100s, 1000s; 60s,
>   1840s, etc.).
>
> The –s is added to show that there is more than one of that particular
>   thing, end of.  No apostrophe needed, thanks.
>
> The ONLY time you add an apostrophe to a plural noun is if you’re
>   showing possession. [...] 4)

Note that the so-called debate ( which I was called out on :)) stemmed from thinking the units, tens, etc were *possessive* nouns modifying "place", i.e., "the ten's (or tens') place."  This makes as much sense as "the red's box" or stranger, "the reds' box".  Clearly, the problem arrises because of the words ending in S.

One final phrase which I hope will make this answer canonical enough:

**The places where the units, tens, and hundreds go.**

(They don't *own* those places :))

---

References:

1) *Harper Collins Dictionary of Mathematics*, New York, 1991. pg. 450

2) *Penguin Dictionary of Mathematics*, London, 1989. pg. 104

3) *The Universal Encyclopedia of Mathematics*, New American Library of Literature, New York, 1964, pg. 163

4) http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/using-the-humble-apostrophe-correctly/

Comment: It would be better to create a canonical answer rather than simply place an addendum at the end. It doesn't matter if edits occur all the way through: the history is retained.

Comment: A canonical answer is THE answer to a question, correct and complete in itself.